# How do I access the entire article of an RSS entry with jGFeed?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile, rss

I I am trying to parse the entire article from an RSS feed but can't find the tag to do that with jgfeed. I am able to get various data for my listview of the posts using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < feeds.entries.length; i++) {                    
    var entry = feeds.entries[i];
    var title = entry.title;
    var link = entry.link;
    var description = entry.content;
    var pubDate = entry.publishedDate;
    if(index == i) {    
        html = "<h1>" + title + "</h1>";
        html += "<p><small>" + pubDate + "</small><br>";
        html += description +"</p>";
        $(id).append(html);
    }               
};
```

However, according to the documentation "entry.content" should be the entire article enclosed in the body tag, however it displays a short snippet when I use it, as shown in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/niAGg.jpg (I want it to display the entire article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out what I can access is dependent on the RSS feed istelf. What I did to get (since I am unable to change the content of the RSS feed) the entire content was to load the page in question into a div and parse out the article I needed.

Answer (score 0):

JGfeed appears to be no longer in existence (at least it's not found in [jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) any more). After looking for an alternative .js for fetching RSS, I found [FeedEk](http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html) which made adding RSS to my phonegap app fairly easy.